# How to parse the Chef server nodes into Rundeck server

Tags: chef-infra, rundeck

I'd like to get the nodes being added to my Chef server into my Rundeck server. I'm successful with getting those nodes into my Rundeck using `chef-rundeck` but it seems that I'm unable to execute commands because the `user@host` column is stated as unset. Is there a way that I can parse the `username` so that Rundeck will automatically set the user@host field?

Comment: Given that chef-rundeck hasn't been touched in years, it might just be out of date.

Comment: @coderanger I'm afraid that it is outdated and won't work anymore but I think it's a luck that it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [better-chef-rundeck](https://github.com/atheiman/better-chef-rundeck). It is improvement of [chef-rundeck](https://github.com/oswaldlabs/chef-rundeck)

Comment: My mistake by indicating I've used chef-rundeck instead of better-chef-rundeck. I've just have to query deeper after the URL which I've thought not possible. Sample query: http://localhost/*:*?username=current_user&hostname=ipaddress&ipaddress&&platform&platform_version